# How to center horizontally 2 vertical views with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I am trying to replicate this simple use case in ConstraintLayout. Basically it is 2 views left aligned to each other, but centered within parent.

[image]

Without CL, it would be as follows

```
FrameLayout
 match_parent
 match_parent

 LinearLayout
   orientation vertical
   width wrap_content
   height wrap_content
   layout_gravity center_horizontal
   gravity left

   View
    width wrap_content
   View
    width wrap_content
```

With CL im struggling how to center them both as a group, I can center them each, with constraints to left parent, right parent, however I want the group to be centered, and withing that group, left gravity. Ive tried using barriers to left and right of the two views, but it doesn center the chain horizontally. Basically I need a horizontal chain out of barriers, I think.

Edit:

```
I----AAA  ----I
I----BBBBB----I
I-------------I
I-------------I
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:background="#303F9F"
        android:text="Short Text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#303F9F"
        android:text="This is a very long text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="start" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The background color is the see the change.

In code get width of the larger TextView and set it to the smaller one.

```
textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView1.measure(0,0);
textView2.measure(0,0);
int len1 = textView1.getMeasuredWidth();
int len2 = textView2.getMeasuredWidth();
if (len1 > len2) {
    textView2.getLayoutParams().width = len1;
} else {
    textView1.getLayoutParams().width = len2;
}
```

And you don't always have to use `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Sorry this is not what am I after. This centers the buttons vertically, not horizontally, and doesnt adress the relative left alignment to each other at all. Ive added one more diagram to question

Comment: @urSus Check update and thats just a sample, but you can modify things.

Comment: okay thanks for your help, but that is silly to do and clearly a missing feature in constraint layout, id rather put those two textviews inside some other viewgroup

Comment: @urSus Its quite logical to not have that if width is wrap_content.

Comment: what do you mean, barriers to the exact same thing, from xml, which is where layouting code should be .. nevermind, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below code will address your problem

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text2 Test2 Test2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/centered"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/centered"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/centered"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two views (view1 being the shorter but at the top and view2 being the longer but at the bottom).

You can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:apps="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        apps:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/view2"
        apps:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        apps:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        apps:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        apps:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        apps:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        apps:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
        apps:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do note `layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle` set to `packed` being used that would have both views pushed together.

Also, observe the constraints between both the views to enable it to be laid out the way you want. View2, in a way, is dictating to view1 on how it is centred. A good thing about using `ConstraintLayout` here is that you don't need to define an extra group (`ViewGroup`) just to lump the two views together, just define the constraints well enough and it will do its magic.

This will produce something like this:
[image]

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost, but both widths have to be wrap_content, so top view could be wider, i.e. "bounding box" should have the width of the wider view, I dont thing ur solution handles this, does it?

Comment: Yea i think that will require 2 constraint layout to work. Barrier / barriers and 2 views inside a constraint layout is not sufficient from what i tried out. Sorry, i can't help you out here.